# Can we register domain in AWS route 53 via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, domain, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudformation

I am new Cloudformation and I am trying to find a Cloudformation script to register the domain, say example.com under Route53. I looked at cloudformation pdf and found nothing related to domain registration under route53.

Any pointers/help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

No. You cant use cloudformation to register domain names, you can only work with already registered domain names.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this whilst looking for another cloudformation issue, and I know it's a tad late but you can add Route53 recordsets using cloudformation, some examples here

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/templates/aws-cloudformation-templates-sa-east-1/

Comment: Hello, please edit your answer and quote a few relevant examples inside your answer (the link can become dead someday).